# Testing an API call using Telerik Fiddler Classic: HTTP 502 Error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, telerik, fiddler, webapi, web-api-testing

I am tyring to call an API using Telerik Fiddler Classic. I haven't done the API. It was made by some guys in another department.

This API call has some parameters, not all are mandatory.

The API call has below appearance:

> https://api.mycompany.es/indicators/59526?start_date=2015-08-16T00%3A00%3A00Z&end_date=2015-09-15T07%3A34%3A17Z

In this case I pass as a parameters, the start and end date to gather some indicators.

The request specifications are below.

**Headers**

```
Accept: application/json; application/vnd.components-api-v1+json
Content-Type: application/json
Host: api.mycompany.es
Authorization: Token token="d5b8abc9686107f493518453339034acc6e2e04405603ea4fb9f6833087372dc"
Cookie:
```

**Route**

```
GET /indicators/59526?start_date=2015-08-16T00%3A00%3A00Z&end_date=2015-09-15T07%3A34%3A17Z
```

**Query Parameters**

```
start_date=2015-08-16T00:00:00Z
end_date=2015-09-15T07:34:17Z
```

**cURL**

```
"https://api.mycompany.es/indicators/59526?start_date=2015-08-16T00%3A00%3A00Z&end_date=2015-09-15T07%3A34%3A17Z" -X GET \
    -H "Accept: application/json; application/vnd.components-api-v1+json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Host: api.mycompany.es" \
    -H "Authorization: Token token=\"d5b8abc9686107f493518453339034acc6e2e04405603ea4fb9f6833087372dc\"" \
    -H "Cookie: "
```

Now I am trying to check it using Telerik Fiddler so I configure it as below screenshots shows.

**Composer**:

[image]

and once executed I get 502 http error and below error message:

> [Fiddler] The connection to 'api.mycompany.es' failed.
> System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS connection
> with server.fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to api.mycompany.es
> (for #37) failed.
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException No se pudo
> realizar una llamada a SSPI; consulte la excepción interna. < No se
> permite la función solicitada Win32 (SChannel) Native Error Code:
> 0x80090302

Also Telerik says:

> No Proxy-Authorization Header is present Authorization Header is
> present: Token
> token="d5b8abc9686107f493518453339034acc6e2e04405603ea4fb9f6833087372dc"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try calling with regular http, not using https

http://api.mycompany.es/indicators/59526?start_date=2015-08-16T00%3A00%3A00Z&end_date=2015-09-15T07%3A34%3A17Z

Comment: @ThomsonMixab Using http instead of https does not work. I get http error 301 (moved permanently) followed by the http error 502 mentioned.

Comment: On which Windows versions do you execute Fiddler? SChannel is the SSL/TLS library of Windows and if the Windows version is too old the SSL/TLS connection may fail.

Comment: @Robert I use Windows 10 64bits home version 21H1 compilation 19043.1110

Comment: Windows 10 should be sufficient. Then I would continue and test the TLS capabilities of the server. If it is a public server use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html otherwise the scripts from https://testssl.sh/ (requires a Linux system) do a great job identifying the TLS capabilities of a server. Or does your company use a special proxy server? The message `No Proxy-Authorization Header is present` might indicate that there is a proxy that requires authentication.

Comment: @Robert I have tried also in a windows 8.1 pro virtual machine and I get the same error. i will check what you say. Thanks.